# Deserializing abstract class Spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Let´s say that I have an abstract class A, that class is inside my MainClass, then I have the implementation of this class B and C. Using ModelAndAttribute I render in some scenarios MainClass with B and in others MainClass with C implementation. Both has the same commit method in the controller, so when I request this ModelAndAttribute in the form I´m waiting MainClass with B or C implementation as was render before, but Spring is it´s consider is A all the time "NullValueInNestedPathException, Invalid property, value of nested property is null".

Any idea if Spring has a mechanism to determine which implementation class is receiving?.

I´ve read this http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/03/entry_372.html and looks promising but I cannot interact or I dont want interact with Jackson about how serialize the entities.

Regards.

Comment: What is `ModelAndAttribute`? What does "that class is inside my MainClass" mean? Jackson has nothing to do with forms. Please share some code.

Comment: ModelAndAttribute it´s a common pattern that use Spring to bind your entities for serializaiton/deserialization into a form

Answer (score 1):

Spring will not decide which implementation to instantiate. 
You will have to add some code to decide which of the 2 class needs to be initiated

We have similar requirement
we pass the type ClassB or ClassC in request parameter

We have method

```
@ModelAttribute (value = "mainClass")
public void populateObjectBasedOnRequestParameter (
            ModelMap modelMap, HttpServletRequest request)
```

this method basically reads the request parameter and instantiate the mainClass with correct implementation of class A

For the form submit

```
 @RequestMapping (value = "/{workItemId}", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "save", consumes =   MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
    public String commit(
                @ModelAttribute ("mainClass")MainClass mainClass,
                BindingResult result, Principal principal,
                HttpServletRequest request, final ModelMap model) {
```

when the form is submitted with request parameter

populateObjectBasedOnRequestParameter() this method is executed so the model map has the initiated implementation for Class A when commit() method is executed

Comment: Yes but A is inside MainClass so in populateObjectBaseOnRequesTParameter how can you specify which instance of A use, create one instance or another (B or C)and pass all the parameter manually to the new instance?. Sounds pretty poor to me.

Comment: we specify the instance of A to user using request parameter based on you application logic like type=B or type=C and we do not pass all the parameter.